Apply different color coding within a cell with OpenPyxl
I have several already made excels that I'd like to format.
One of these formatting is to set a part of a cell in green, and the other part in red.
For the sake of this example, let's imagine cell "A1" is filled with "Hello World!".
I'd like to set "Hello" with a green font and "World!" with a red font, within the same cell.
I know this is possible using either xlsxwriter or xlwings, but both aren't available for my case as :

I already have my Excels that I want to tune, and xlsxwriter only writes on new sheets.
Xlwings is not available on my environment.

Thus I've been trying to use good old OpenPyxl library, which from my understanding is not the best for what I'd like to do..
Let's try the following example, that simply (should) write 'Hello' in red and "World!" in black within an excel sheet.
from openpyxl import Workbook 
from openpyxl.cell.rich_text import TextBlock, CellRichText 
from openpyxl.cell.text import InlineFont  
wb = Workbook() 
ws = wb.active  
red = InlineFont(color='FF000000') 
rich_string1 = CellRichText([TextBlock(red, 'Hello'), "World!"])  
ws["A1"] = rich_string1  
wb.save("hello_world_richtext.xlsx")  

Results are not as expected as it's writting in black..   I have been trying several things, such as writting in a seperate sheet with xlsxwriter and copy paste with openpyxl to the right location, but it loses formatting.   Do any of you have an idea on how I could proceed ?   Thanks in advance

Openpyxl is perfect for what you need, just apply the colours  correctly as noted in the answer. If you have 4 pairs then the first pair is the alpha then it's RGB.

FF000000 is black, not red. Red is 00FF0000. (To be more specific, as @Charlie Clark mentioned, in aRGB 000000 is black and FF0000 is red, while the first two characters are ignored for cell styles by openpyxl, check out their documentation.)
Other than that, your code should work. It just puts black and black next to each other so it's not visible.

Thanks a lot, stupid mistake from my side !

Colours are (a)RGB with the alpha (also known as transparency) an optional prefix. So, while FF0000 is red, FF000000 is black –FF+ 000000 –  that is completely opaque. In general, unless you're really interested in the level of transparency, it's easier just to use RGB.
